# Maximal ideals of ring of continous functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Can we characterize all the maximal ideals of the ring of real valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$? One type of such ideal is the evaluation at a certain point and another is the maximal ideal containing all continuous real valued functions with compact support. What are the other type of maximal ideals ?

Comment: I think there’s more than one maximal ideal containing the functions with compact support… my understanding is that this ring has a very complicated structure.

Comment: Yes surely it does have a complicated structure. Can you briefly discuss your idea ?

Comment: For any partition of $A\cup\overline A=\mathbb R$ into two unbounded sets, the ideal of functions whose support is compact outside of $A$ strictly contains the ideal of functions with compact support.

Comment: Hopefully the set of continuous functions tending to $0$ at infinity ?

Comment: @JeanMarie unfortunately that's not an ideal.  It contains $1/(x^2+1)$ but not $(x^2+1)/(x^2+1) = 1$.